# TextInputEditText receiving keyboard events without focus

Tags: java, android

I'm using an activity with a ViewPager to scroll between 3 fragments. In this activity, I have overriden dispatchKeyEvent to be able to propagate keyevents generated by the device's scanner to the correct fragment depending on what is scanned.

One of these fragments has some TextInputLayout/TextInputEditText so the user is able to manually add data. When he presses "Done" on SoftKeyboard I set the data, hide the keyboard and clear the focus by calling **getActivity().getCurrentFocus().clearFocus()** (Null checked). Now, if I use the scanner again the input gets written on these TextInputEditText's, even when getActivity().getCurrentFocus() returns null. Main Activity is no longer able to catch dispatchKeyEvent.

Any ideas ideas would be highly appreciated.

Switching fragments on ViewPager and coming back to this one seems the only way to getting it back working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Cleared focus from parent Activity and then requested focus on ViewPager.